# How can we download a file that kept at FTP Location and copy to specified destination folder by hitting an URL using JAVA

Tags: java, ftp

How can we download a file that kept at FTP Location and copy to specified destination folder by hitting an URL using JAVA.
Should We prefer to use Java Application or Web Application?

Comment: Please don't copy and paste the bulk of your question into the title

Comment: Are you asking how to make a service which can be called by URL to copy content from ftp to some other location?

Comment: Yes Brett. I want to know how to make a service